# Self-made LinkedList and Node

Tags: java, linked-list, generics, comparative-review

I have recently made two kinds of linked lists in Java. I know that there is one with generic and one without. However, what I am really concerned about is which style should be used mostly (or which style should be used as the main style to implement the `LinkedList` structure). When talking about these two styles, could you ignore the singly or doubly type, but mainly concentrate on the structure?

The first one is a singly `LinkedList`, but most of the functions are coded inside the `Node` class, and the linked list class only contains some easy functions which is used to call the functions inside the `Node` class.

```
package chapter2linkedlist;
import java.util.*;
public class LinkNode {

private Node root;

class Node {
    private String data;
    private Node nextNode;

    public Node() {
    }

    public Node(String data) {
        this();
        this.setData(data);
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void add(Node nextNode) {
        if (this.nextNode == null) {
            this.nextNode = nextNode;
        } else {
            this.nextNode.add(nextNode);
        }
    }

    public String getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return this.nextNode;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.data);
        if (this.nextNode != null) {
            this.nextNode.print();
        }
    }

    public boolean search(String data) {
        if (data == this.data) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (this.nextNode == null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return this.nextNode.search(data);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean delete(Node previousNode, String data) {
        boolean isDeleted = false;
        if (this.data.equals(data)) {
            previousNode.nextNode = this.nextNode;
            isDeleted = true;
        } else {
            if (this.nextNode != null) {
                this.nextNode.delete(this, data);
            }
        }
        return isDeleted;
    }
}

public void addNode(String data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    if (this.root == null) {
        this.root = newNode;
    } else {
        this.root.add(newNode);
    }
}

public void printNode() {
    if (this.root != null) {
        this.root.print();
    }
}

public boolean isContain(String data) {
    return this.root.search(data);
}

public void deleteNode(String data) {
    if (this.root.data.equals(data)) {
        if (this.root.getNext() == null) {
            this.root = new Node();
        } else {
            this.root = this.root.getNext();
        }
    } else {
        this.root.delete(root, data);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LinkNode linkNode = new LinkNode();
    linkNode.addNode("A");
    linkNode.addNode("B");
    linkNode.addNode("C");
    linkNode.addNode("D");
    linkNode.addNode("E");
    linkNode.addNode("F");
    linkNode.addNode("G");

    System.out.println("before delete nodes");
    linkNode.printNode();
    linkNode.deleteNode("A");
    linkNode.deleteNode("E");
    System.out.println("after delete nodes");
    linkNode.printNode();

    LinkedList<String> testList = new LinkedList<String>();
    StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        strBuffer.append(i);
        testList.add(strBuffer.toString());
    }
    System.out.println(testList);
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < testList.size(); i++){
        if(testList.get(i).equals("0123456") || testList.get(i).equals("012345678")){
            testList.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(testList);


}

}
```

The second one is a doubly class, but most functions are implemented inside the LinkedList class, the Node class only have some basic functions which is used to operate its own variables.

```
package chapter2linkedlist;
public class SelfLinkedList<T> {

private Node<T> root;
private int countSize;

public SelfLinkedList() {
    root = null;
    countSize = 0;
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return this.countSize == 0;
}

public int size() {
    return this.countSize;
}

private Node<T> getRootNode() {
    if (null != this.root) {
        return this.root;
    }
    return null;
}

private Node<T> getLastNode() {
    if (null != root) {
        Node<T> currentNode = root;
        while (currentNode.getNextNode() != null) {
            currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
        }
        return currentNode;
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean append(T var) {
    Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(var);
    if (null == this.root || countSize == 0) {
        this.root = newNode;
        countSize++;
        return true;
    }

    Node<T> currentNode = root;
    while (currentNode.getNextNode() != null) {
        currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
    }
    currentNode.setNextNode(newNode);
    newNode.setPreviousNode(currentNode);
    countSize++;
    return true;
}

public boolean removeFirst() {
    if (null == this.root) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.root != null || this.root.getNextNode() == null) {
        this.root = null;
        countSize--;
        return true;
    }
    this.root = this.root.getNextNode();
    this.root.prevNode = null;
    countSize--;
    return true;
}

public boolean removeLast() {
    if (null == this.root) {
        return false;
    }
    if (null != this.root || null == this.root.getNextNode()) {
        this.root = null;
        countSize--;
        return true;
    }
    Node<T> currentNode = root;
    while (currentNode.getNextNode() != null) {
        currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
    }
    currentNode.getPreviousNode().nextNode = null;
    countSize--;
    return true;
}

public boolean removeNodeByIndex(int index) {
    if (index > countSize - 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (index == 0) {
        return this.removeFirst();
    } else if (index == countSize - 1) {
        return this.removeLast();
    } else {
        Node<T> currentNode = this.searchNodeByIndex(index);
        currentNode.getPreviousNode()
                .setNextNode(currentNode.getNextNode());
        currentNode.getNextNode().setPreviousNode(
                currentNode.getPreviousNode());
        countSize--;
        return true;
    }

}

public boolean removeNodeByData(T var) {
    if (this.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    Node<T> currentNode = searchNodeByData(var);
    if (null == currentNode) {
        return false;
    }
    if (currentNode.getNextNode() != null
            && currentNode.getPreviousNode() != null) {
        currentNode.getNextNode().setPreviousNode(
                currentNode.getPreviousNode());
        currentNode.getPreviousNode()
                .setNextNode(currentNode.getNextNode());
        countSize--;
    } else if (currentNode.getNextNode() != null
            && currentNode.getPreviousNode() == null) {
        currentNode.getNextNode().prevNode = null;
        countSize--;
    } else {
        currentNode.getPreviousNode().nextNode = null;
        countSize--;
    }

    return true;
}

public Node<T> searchNodeByData(T var) {
    if (this.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    if (var == root.getData()) {
        return root;
    }
    Node<T> currentNode = root;
    while (currentNode.getNextNode() != null) {
        currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
        if (var == currentNode.getData()) {
            return currentNode;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public Node<T> searchNodeByIndex(int index) {
    if (this.isEmpty() || index > countSize - 1) {
        return null;
    }
    int count = 0;
    Node<T> currentNode = root;
    while (currentNode.getNextNode() != null) {
        if (count == index) {
            break;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
        count++;
    }
    return currentNode;
}

class Node<T> {
    private Node<T> prevNode;
    private Node<T> nextNode;
    T data;

    public Node() {
    }

    public Node(T var) {
        this.data = var;
    }

    public boolean setData(T var) {
        this.data = var;
        return true;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    private void setNextNode(Node<T> n) {
        if (null != this.nextNode) {
            this.nextNode.prevNode = n;
            n.nextNode = this.nextNode;
        }
        this.nextNode = n;
        n.prevNode = this;
    }

    private void setPreviousNode(Node<T> n) {
        if (null != this.prevNode) {
            n.prevNode = this.prevNode;
            this.prevNode.nextNode = n;
        }
        this.prevNode = n;
        n.nextNode = this;

    }

    private Node<T> getNextNode() {
        if (null != this.nextNode) {
            return this.nextNode;
        }
        return null;

    }

    private Node<T> getPreviousNode() {
        if (null != this.prevNode) {
            return this.prevNode;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

Could someone help me out about which style should be used with? I am not so professional in Java, so I cannot distinguish the main difference between these two styles. Should I choose the one with the most functions inside the `Node` class or the other one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Singly link or doubly link?

The choice of implementing a linked list as singly-linked or doubly-linked is not a matter of "style", it's a matter of requirements.
A doubly-linked list is useful when you need to manipulate both ends of the list.

And yes, you should use a generic node so that you can store any kind of object in the list.

#### Cleaning up `LinkNode.Node`

The class `Node` nested in `LinkNode` should be `private static`.
Private, to hide this implementation detail from the outside,
and static,
because the class doesn't need to access data in the enclosing class.

Since `Node.data` never changes, it can be `final`.
To make that work, you'll need to rework the constructors:

```
public Node() {
    this.data = null;
}

public Node(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

The originals were very badly written:

> ```
> public Node() {
> }
>
> public Node(String data) {
>     this();
>     this.setData(data);
> }
>
> public void setData(String data) {
>     this.data = data;
> }
> ```

This is bad because:

- A method with an empty body is always a bad sign
- Calling `this()` from the other constructor is pointless
- A constructor should not call methods that can be overridden in children
- `setData` is not used anywhere else, and certainly it should not be public.
  The way I rewrote the constructors above makes this method completely unnecessary.

---

This method is bad in many ways:

> ```
> public boolean search(String data) {
>     if (data == this.data) {
>         return true;
>     } else {
>         if (this.nextNode == null) {
>             return false;
>         } else {
>             return this.nextNode.search(data);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Normally you should not compare objects using `==`.
This expression will only be true of the instances on the left and the right side are the same instance. You should use `.equals()` instead.

The `else` branch can be simplified to this:

```
return this.nextNode != null && this.nextNode.search(data);
```

Also, since the method returns a boolean,
the name "contains" would be more natural instead of "search".
Later I noticed the "isContain" method, which is completely unnecessary,
since it simply delegates to "search".

#### Avoid random access of elements in a linked list

Do not iterate over a linked list like this:

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < testList.size(); i++){
>     if(testList.get(i).equals("...")) {
>         // ...
>     }
> }
> ```

Random access of list elements like this (with `.get(i)`) is inefficient with lists.
Use a `ListIterator` instead, like this:

```
ListIterator<String> iter = testList.listIterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String item = iter.next();
    if (item.equals("0123456") || item.equals("012345678")) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

#### Possible simplifications

Instead of this:

> ```
> private Node<T> getRootNode() {
>     if (null != this.root) {
>         return this.root;
>     }
>     return null;
> }
> ```

This is exactly the same but much shorter and clearer:

```
private Node<T> getRootNode() {
    return this.root;
}
```

---

Instead of this:

> ```
> boolean isDeleted = false;
> if (this.data.equals(data)) {
>     previousNode.nextNode = this.nextNode;
>     isDeleted = true;
> } else {
>     if (this.nextNode != null) {
>         this.nextNode.delete(this, data);
>     }
> }
> return isDeleted;
> ```

You can simplify by using an early return:

```
if (this.data.equals(data)) {
    previousNode.nextNode = this.nextNode;
    return true;
}
if (this.nextNode != null) {
    this.nextNode.delete(this, data);
}
return false;
```

#### Naming

The method name `printNode` is misleading:
it suggests printing a single node,
but it prints the entire linked list.

#### StringBuilder is recommended instead of StringBuffer

Unless you have a specific requirement to use `StringBuffer`,
use `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out of this confusion, really appreciate it.